# Rails 4 asset pipeline and image placement No route matches [GET] "images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using the download builder for [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/) to generate a CSS file.  For CSS rules such as:

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

The generated css is looking for `images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png`, but that doesn't work with the asset pipeline.

I've tried putting the images in `public/images` and `assets/images`, but that still doesn't change the fact that rails will always barf on trying to find `/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png`.  (error is `No route matches [GET] "images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png"`)

So where am I supposed to put the images??

Comment: Can you change the generated css?

Comment: I don't see a way to change it in the generator.  I could always do some search and replace in the downloaded file.  But if I do search and replace, do I just change it from images to assets/images?  Would that still work in production?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the generated css put your images inside public/images and change

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

to

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

Using a relative path will solve your problem.

Comment: Such a silly thing to get tripped up on :p  You're right, it should be absolute, not relative.

Comment: And, for clarification, the images go in public/images not app/assets/images